# Kotlin Any as parameter

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on Retrofit in Kotlin.

Now, I want to create only one function ( API ) which accepts different pojos as the parameter.

I have created a function with "Any" as parameter.
Now If I try to pass one Model, it gives me compile time error of MyModel cannot convert to Any.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you can you should show your code in the post.  A small bit of code which exhibits the error. 
 I've posted an answer but I'm kind of guessing at the exact problem without seeing some code and error message.

Comment: a piece of code might help... let us know what you have tried.

Answer (score 4):

Change the parameter type to

`Any?`

This allows possible null values to be passed.  More information about Any vs Any? and interaction with java is shown in this post: [kotlin any or kotlin any?](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-any-or-kotlin-any-which-is-equivalent-java-lang-object/8614)